# Can you use guest account on system with full disk encryption?

Tags: 18.04, encryption, guest-session

I read somewhere that encrypted home directory using encryptfs is not offered as option anymore with latest release.

Can I use a guest account on system with full disk encryption?

Comment: What is your question/ problem?

Comment: OP seems to be referring to canonical discontinuing eCryptfs-Support (for encrypted `home/user`-folders) in favor of full disk encryption due to eCryptfs pakages not being actively maintained anymore

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do with the guest account? The guest account has no permanent home do I dont understand what either encryption option has to do with anything

Comment: Ah! I see. Your totally right! I confused the guest account with other user accounts. My bad. I'll update my answer to accommodate for that.

Comment: @Panther If you want someone to br able to start computer and use guest session and not give the password.

Comment: Oh, guest session seems to be disabled in 18.04 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession

Comment: If you use whole disc encryption,  luks allows more than 1 password,  so set a second  temporary password to boot.  There really is no way around https://access.redhat.com/solutions/230993.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

If you use full disk encryption - which is the only option in the 18.04 installer - you will not be able to use 'Guest'-accounts without giving everybody your encryption key. 
This is true not only for 18.04, but for every release before, if you used full disk encryption.

**Backgrounds:**

For 18.04 Canonical decided to not offer `eCryptfs` anymore since the package is (or was) not actively maintained. Hence, securty issues and broken user experience could have a negative impact on the distribution itself, which clearly should not happen on an LTS release.

Also, in favor of better data protection, LUKS can be used to encrypt the whole disk.
`ecryptfs-utils` however was moved to Universe Repo, so you can install it from there.

To answer your question:

If you still want to encrypt your users home directories (i.e. on multi user machines) you'd be better off **not** enabling encryption during installation and then install the `ecryptfs-utils` package later on to finally encrypt your user home directories.